# TCPIP Socket Listener Performance Issue

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp

I have a fairly straightforward windows service that implements a C# TCPIP socket listener service.  The service is a proprietary but simple protocol.  It works accurately and reliably even under heavy load.  However, the performance is inadequate for the purpose it has to serve, and I have been working to fix this.

I don't know what the architecture is officially called.  But it is the basic asynchronous implementation (IAsyncResult state objects,  AcceptCallback(), ReadCallback(), etc.).

Here is the basic performance issue:  As part of the response to a request, the service has to make a call out to a remote service (operated by some independent service provider).  Typically, the responses to this operation take (approximately) one second.  However, if I load up 20 test clients (running as independent consumers from multiple machines), the one second responses from the remote service stretch out to five seconds or more.  I have used tracing to confirm that all of this five seconds is "within the code that conducts those remote transactions".  Tracing also confirms that the server is handling its requests concurrently as expected and not stacking them up.

That said, I have done independent testing that proves the remote service can easily handle its stuff in the one second time frame regardless of the load (that service is operated by a large well-known company that knows what it is doing and does it for innumerable organizations - I am confident it is not their problem).  I have altered my load tests to perform this I/O directly rather than utilizing the service and it achieves the one-second turn-arounds.

Finally, as a test, I implemented multiple listeners within my service that listen on different ports and had my load tester clients distribute their requests amongst the ports.  Doing this increased the performance in relation to the number of ports (two listeners == approx 2X performance)

Now, I know that listening on multiple ports is not the correct solution and should not make a difference.  But this does tell me there is some flaw in my implementation that is interfering with the ability to recycle the listeners.  Or, it indicates that the drivers for the remote service are being starved of cycles and not able to respond expediently (though I am inclined not to believe this scenario).

The throughput requirements don't seem that high to me - we only have to handle around two incoming requests a second.  We only need to be able to respond within around two seconds or so on average.  But the five to seven second responses actually bring *our* consumer down (which, in itself, is odd but we have no control over that).

I have Listener.MaxConnections set to 2500.  But making this number 5000 or 20 doesn't affect this issue.

I am hoping for some advice on how to figure this one out.  I suspect I am performing some business-layer code within the wrong context.  But I'm not seeing it.

Regards,

Comment: What are you running this on? Non-server Windows has a default limit on the number of half-open TCP connections which you may be running into, if I remember right, that limit is 10.

Comment: Good point.  However, this is running on a licensed Server 2008 R2 instance.  It *is* a VMWARE instance, which concerns me a little.  But the hypervisor hardware is capable enough so I think it is ok.

Comment: Oh, and the logging (which is queued to avoid causing its own impact) shows that we generally have as many "in process" connections as we do test clients - which is currently 20.

Comment: Did you set the Socket.NoDelay property ?

Comment: Well, no.  This is something I was unaware of.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: The review I just did indicated that the default value is "false", that "false" specifies the use of the "Nagle" algorithm and, (at least in that source's opinion), that "the majority of network applications should use the Nagle algorithm".  So, by not setting the property I am operating in their recommended configuration.  What is your recommendation for this property?

Comment: The Nagle algorithm delays sending of small chunk of data to complete them with more data, in order to "group" separate sending in a single packet. Therefore, if your TCP send contains a small amount of bytes, the effective sending may be delayed.

Comment: So, you were recommending NoDelay = true.  I have tried this, and there *does* seem to be an improvement.  However, setting the value to "false" or not setting it appears to show the same improvement now.  So, I have to go back and make sure I haven't somehow altered my test platform.  You have provided me some encouragement at the very least :).  Actually, I remember I testing in the debugger now... I should inject this change into pre-prod to see how it works on a real server.

Comment: Huh.  Just to complicate things, I discover that there is significant performance difference between our development environment and our preprod - with development being faster.  Under a load of 40 load test instances, the development server is turning around requests at an average of 5.5 seconds while pre-prod is 11.5 to 13 seconds.  I had the hardware guys check this out and they insist the provisioning is almost identical, but that pre-prod is Server 2012 and DEV is 2008R2.

Comment: ... (hmmm... carriage return posts a comment - sorry).  Anyway, if this is really an OS issue it doesn't belong on this forum.  I still suspect there is a socket-level problem to be found, though...  I'm using the "NoDelay" advice, regardless.

Comment: It wasn't different server OS after all.  Both machines are very similar 2008R2 virtual servers on capable VMWare hosts.